# Parse WRL file to X3D

Tags: parsing, x3d, wrl

Well the problem I have is that I need to transform a WRL file to a X3D xml file, but for this I can't find API's that can get code from the file.

Well first I manually saw what tags were needed for the X3D file, and then I was trying with open source software to modify it by exporting it to that file, but in some cases it doesn't work and I would like to do it by code.

Comment: check out MP4Box from Gpac (https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/MP4Box). I used it years ago to convert wrl, bifs and x3d files. Should still do the work today especially as the project looks to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

view3dscene https://castle-engine.io/view3dscene.php is a part of the Castle Game engine project. view3dscene by itself is a very capable viewer of both .wrl files -- also known as VRML encoding -- and X3D files. WRL files read by view3dscene can be saved as X3D